# Cannot add Static Resource

Tags: static-resources

I am in a developer sandbox within Salesforce, and am trying to follow the "Build the Account Map Display" Trailhead.

When I log into the sandbox and access "Static Resources", there is no "New" button.  I have checked that Lightning Experience is active and that the Organization Edition is Developer Edition.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the New button, it is tiny and in the middle of the table header.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that your profile has these System [Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources_edit.htm&type=5) listed here to be able to Edit/ Create static resources.

Comment: Where do I check the user permissions?

Comment: Setup-> Profiles ->whatever profile is assigned to your user/ the user that needs access On the profile look at System Permissions

Comment: Another way is Setup -> <your user's full name in the search bar on left side> and click the profile on your user

Comment: The user has Customize Applications permission, being a System Administrator, yet I do not see the New Static Resource link.

Comment: can you provide any SS of your view?

Comment: I finally saw the button - it is tiny and in the middle of the header.

Comment: sounds like a monitor scaling issue. Sometimes happens on my 4k if i attach an external monitor that is not 4k